# Splitting a row into columns

Tags: ruby

I have one file which is the content is like this:

```
first;48548a;48954a,48594B
second;58757a;5875b
third;58756a;58576b;5867d;56894d;45864a
```

And I want to change the format like this:

```
first;48548a
first;48954a
first;48594B
second;58757a
second;5875b
third;58756a
third;58576b
third;5867d
third;56894d
third;45864a
```

In Bash, I can use this cmmand to make it happen:

```
awk -F\; '{for(n=2; n<=NF; n++) { printf("%s;%s\n",$1,$n); }}' input.txt
```

but now I am trying to do so with Ruby. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
IO.readlines("input.txt").each do |line|
  num, *data = line.strip.split(/[;,]/)
  data.each do |s|
    puts "#{num};#{s}"
  end
end
```

Note that both @evfwcqcg and I are accounting for what may well be a typo, the comma as a record separator on the first line.

Comment: Personally I would prefer `num, *data = line.strip.split(/[;,]/)` to `shift`ing, since it doesn't mutate anything in place and `data`'s meaning isn't changed over its lifetime.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes, I like that better, too!  Thanks for the suggestion; I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Darshan,, what is the function of (*) in *data?

Comment: @adhown That's called the splat operator. Google for a proper explanation, but the short version is that in this case it makes it so `num` gets the first element of the array generated on the right-hand side, and `data` gets an array of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = <<-STR
first;48548a;48954a,48594B
second;58757a;5875b
third;58756a;58576b;5867d;56894d;45864a
STR

def disp(number, *elems)
  puts elems.map { |e| "#{number};#{e}" }
end

ar = s.split.each {|x| disp(*x.split(/[;,]/)) }

# => first;48548a
# => first;48954a
# => first;48594B
# => second;58757a
# => second;5875b
# => third;58756a
# => third;58576b
# => third;5867d
# => third;56894d
# => third;45864a
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in assuming you're reading this into your script as a text file? To get you started, `File.open(textfile).each do (code code code) end`
From there, take a look at what evfwcqcg has to say with splitting up the lines like this:

`File.open(textfile).each do |line|
x = line.split(/[;,]/)
end`

I THINK. I'm not too sure, but I think that argument is regex?? Someone explain please. Then, that breaks up the lines into their own arrays (one at a time). From there, you just loop through them, keeping your `line[0]` at the beginning of each printed line.

Comment: You're asking a question about your own answer?

Comment: Hi Brad,, your assumptions is right. I don't quite understand what his (evfwcqcg) explain above.

Comment: @BradRice, it's not *illegal*, but if you need to flat out ask people if your explanation is correct, you maybe shouldn't be answering (or at least not until you verify yourself). Answers, in general, shouldn't have questions in them, that's why they're *answers* `:)`.